# Regular expression ((MM)*N{1,3})|((N{1,3})(MM)*) not matching what I think it should

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that would match pairs of Ms and up to 3 Ns consecutively in any order so

- MMMMNN would match
- MMNNN would match
- NNNMM would match
- NMMMM would also match

I used the following regular expression:

```
((MM)*N{1,3})|(N{1,3}(MM)*)
```

each term matches alone but when I put the `|` between them it doesn't seem to match both possibilities. I used http://regex101.com/ to test it.

What regular expression would match those?

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect a bug in Regex101.  With `(N{1,3}(MM)*)|((MM)*N{1,3})` it produces what I'd expect.  Reverse the order as in the question, and it ignores the M's in search strings with 1-3 N's followed by one or more pairs of M's (it handles 0 pairs of M's OK).  I see no justification for the difference.  I did use the `g` option in the box for qualifiers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: There's no bug, it's just that `(MM)*` can match nothing.  Your reversed regex works because the branch that starts with `N{1,3}` will fail the string doesn't start with `N`, but `(MM)*` never fails.  Shouldn't that have been `(MM)+`?

Comment: @AlanMoore: My immediate reaction was "I didn't turn off greediness with `*?`, so the pattern should be matching as many pairs of M's after the list of N's as possible, shouldn't it?"  But after another moment or two's cogitation, I know what you're driving at — and you're right — but I'm not sure you've explained it well yet, and I know I haven't.  —— Mrfuzzy: the problem is in your/my expectations, not in the regex system.

Comment: Unless I'm misremembering, when looking at alternatives in a regex like `(A|B)`, the regex engine attempts to match `A`, and if it finds a match at a given position, it won't attempt to find a match for B at that position, even if there could be a longer match for B from the same position. In your regex `((MM)*N{1,3})|(N{1,3}(MM)*)`, at the first position in a string such as `NMMMM`, the first alternative matches (zero pairs of M's plus an N), so the second alternative isn't checked at all. So, as has been hinted, you probably need to make the alternatives require one or more pairs of M's.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand it very clearly now. Problem is this was a part of a bigger problem where it is possible that MM doesn't appear at all that's why I can't use (MM)+. I will try to figure out a work around to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This matches all the examples you have:

```
(N{1,3}(MM)+)|((MM)+N{1,3})
```

The question is however, if 'up to 3' should include `zero` instances?

**Edit**: The comment is correct, removed the extra plus.

Comment: The `((MM)+)+` fragment is overkill; it won't match anything that `(MM)+` won't match, and may make the regex engine work hard.  It is fairly clear from the question that there must be at least one N (the `{1,3}` makes that pretty much unambiguous); an alternative important question is 'must there be at least one pair of M's, or is NNN (and NN and N) allowed to match'?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you...

```
(MMN{0,3})|(N{0,3}MM)
```

Comment: Can you accept the answer? I updated it to remove a bug.